# phpのファイルがphp言語として読み込まれない

Tags: php, windows, apache, windows-10

xamppを使用せずにPHP環境構築をする練習をしています。
visual studio,Apache,phpはインストール済みです。
apacheとphpはパスが通っていることを確認しました。
（どこからapache phpコマンドを打っても-vでバージョン確認可能）

`http://localhost`
でIt works!
は表示できます。

htdocs配下にphpinfo.php

を作成し、`http://localhost/phpinfo.php` にchromeで接続すると中身がそのまま表示されます。
firefoxだとテキストエディタで開こうとします。

php.iniの編集は以下のページを参考にしました。

[【初心者向け】0から導入するPHPの環境構築 Windows10版 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/narito/items/d4b6165376f141dce939)

環境
Windows10
PHP 7.4.4
Apache　2.4.43
visual studio 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache経由でPHPを利用するためのモジュールを読み込む記述を、Apacheの設定ファイルに追加しましたか？あなたが提示したURLの以下の部分です。またhttpd.confの設定を変更した場合、設定を反映するにはApacheを再起動する必要があります。

```
1. LoadModule(74~184行目)

ここの行には無数に#LoadModule ~が並んでいると思うので一番最後の行にLoadModule php7_module "C:/php-7.3.0/php7apache2_4.dll"を書き込んでください.（php-7.3.0はPHPのファイルにつけた名前にしてください）

httpd.conf
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so

（中略）

#LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
LoadModule php7_module "C:/php-7.3.0/php7apache2_4.dll"  ←コレ！
```

Comment: ご指摘いただいた通りここが原因でした。
dllのパスが違ったので修正しましたら、phpinfo.phpのページが表示できました。