# RHEL環境でブラウザに表示したときPHPがPHPとして認識されない

Tags: php, aws, apache, rhel

AWSのRed Hat Enterprise LinuxでPHPの環境を作成ました。
ローカルからTera TermでSSH接続しています。
ブラウザでphpinfoを表示し、phpの動作確認を行いたいのですが、コードがすべてそのまま表示されてしまいます。
以前ローカルでも似た現象が起こりました。
[phpのファイルがphp言語として読み込まれない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/65327/php%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8Cphp%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

以前の質問の回答にあったdllファイルがRHEL上で見当たりません。
そもそもdllファイルが原因であるのかも定かではありません。

ちなみにphpに関しては`php73 --version`でしっかりバージョン情報は表示されます。
またapacheに関してはhttp:IPアドレスでapacheのページがブラウザに表示できています。
ですのでphpもapacheもインストールまでは問題なく済んでいるかと思います。

原因はphp.iniやhttpd.confの問題でしょうか。
違う何かでしょうか。
解決の糸口やアドバイス、参考ページなどがありましたがご教授ください。
よろしくお願いします。

環境
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2
Apache2.4
php7.3

-追記-
通常のphp.iniのディレクトリパスの例は`etc/php.ini`が一般的のようですが、当方のRHELではremiレポジトリを作成しているので`etc/opt/remi/php73/php.ini`に入っています。
これは何か関係がありそうでしょうか。

php.iniやhttpd.comfの中身はどのあたりを追記すれば参考になりますでしょうか。
自身では主にドキュメントルートやポートの確認をしました。

Comment: OSや各ツールはバージョンによって対応方法が異なる場合があるので、なるべくバージョンを明記しましょう。併せて、「原因はphp.iniやhttpd.confの問題でしょうか」と思うなら、これらの中身も質問文に含めておいた方が余計なやり取りを減らせて回答も付きやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: 前回の質問も拝見しました。前回はローカル環境だったので,Windowsのdllが原因だったと思いますが、今回はRHELなので、*.dllは関係ないです。サーバで使用しているphp.iniやhttpd.confを見てみないと何とも言えないと思います。

Comment: コメントを拝見した上で追記しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dnf install php73` だと php コマンドしかインストールされないようです。
Apache httpd 用モジュールは `php73-php` パッケージに含まれますので、`dnf install php73-php` でインストールします。

Comment: php73-php-7.3.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64のインストールが実行されました。apacheの再起動をかけましたが、まだphpのコードがそのまま表示されてしまいます。

Comment: インストールしたパッケージのリリース番号が「.el7」となっていますが、「.el8」ですよね？
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-php73-php.conf および /etc/httpd/conf.d/php73-php.conf は存在しますか？

Comment: 再度確認しましたが「.el7」でした。 /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-php73-php.conf と/etc/httpd/conf.d/php73-php.confどちらもございます。

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2 に誤って remi-release-7.rpm を入れてしまったのでしょうか？
それとも、本当は Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.x なのでしょうか？
前者なら、remi 関連をすべてアンインストールしてやり直すか、新規インスタンス起動からやり直した方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: 前者です、linuxは8.2でremiが7です。知識不足で申し訳ないでのすが、linuxは8.2にはremi-release-7.rpmではなく、remi-release-8.rpmを入れるべきという認識でいいのでしょうか。

Comment: はい、remi-release-8.rpm です。